# Rails execute edit when show action is called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias

I have got a rails controller where the `edit` action displays a form where all values of the object can be changed. So now when a user accesses `/controller/1` I want to do exactly the same as if `/controller/1/edit` was visited.

I have to achieve this without modifying or adding a route, nor using a `redirect_to` in the controller. Otherwise JQueryMobile would track the redirect in it's history.

I have tried to do this the ruby way by `alias :show :edit` but it failed because rails was still searching for `show.html.erb`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can define your `show` action as follows:

```
def show
  edit
  render :action => :edit
end
```

but that's really awkward. And it definitely will ignore all before filters if you have any for `edit` action.

Why can't you use some rules in routes for that? Or better not sending user to `show` action at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom route to map the show action to the edit action.

```
resources :users, except: :show do
  get "", as: "", on: :member, to: :edit
end
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not seem to work (tested in rails 4.0.4) because the custom defined routes takes precedence over the ones defined by `resources :users' - this means that a GET to /users/new will trigger the edit action with id: 'new'.

Comment: it can be fixed by hacking the routes to force precedence of the new route - edited the answer to reflect this